# How to effect to video in fabric.js

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, html5-canvas, fabricjs

I want use image-filters to video.
(http://fabricjs.com/image-filters)

but It's stops video.
How to effect to video in fabric.js?

For example, how do I change the color of a video?

https://codepen.io/html5andblog/pen/dmKJH

↑I do not use CSS filter.
Can someone explain please?

Thanks.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="SHIFT-JIS">
<title>sample</title>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fabric.js/2.2.3/fabric.min.js"></script>
<script>


$(document).ready(function() {

    canvas = new fabric.Canvas('c');
    canvas.setWidth(480);
    canvas.setHeight(360);

    var video1El = document.getElementById('video1');
    var video1 = new fabric.Image(video1El, {
      left: 0,
      top: 0
    });

    canvas.add(video1);
    video1.getElement().load();


    $(document.body).on('click', '#play' ,function(){
        video1.getElement().play();

        //↓It's stops video.
        /*
        var filter = new fabric.Image.filters.BlendColor({
            color:'red',
            mode: 'tint',
            alpha: 0.5
        });
            canvas.item(0).filters.push(filter);
        canvas.item(0).applyFilters();
        */


    });




    fabric.util.requestAnimFrame(function render() {
      canvas.renderAll();
      fabric.util.requestAnimFrame(render);
    });

});
</script>

</head>
<body>
<button id="play">play</button>
<canvas id="c" width="300" height="300"></canvas>

<video id="video1" style="display: none" class="canvas-img" width="480" height="360">
  <source id="video_src1" src="https://html5demos.com/assets/dizzy.mp4" type="video/mp4">
</video>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: If webgl is not available it wil be terribly slow, just that you know it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Ok so it can be done, the problem is that fabricJS to be faster cache textures and avoid pulling them in the video card every applyfilters to save time.

In this case i had to modify your code n 2 places:

1) applyFilters need to be run each animation frame

2) the cache for the texture must be deleted each time

The hardest part was finding a video with cors enabled.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

    canvas = new fabric.Canvas('c');
    canvas.setWidth(480);
    canvas.setHeight(360);

    var video1El = document.getElementById('video1');
    var video1 = new fabric.Image(video1El, {
      left: 0,
      top: 0
    });

    canvas.add(video1);
    video1El.load();


    $(document.body).on('click', '#play' ,function(){
        video1El.play();
        var filter = new fabric.Image.filters.BlendColor({
            color:'red',
            mode: 'tint',
            alpha: 0.5
        });
        video1.filters = [filter];
    });




    fabric.util.requestAnimFrame(function render() {
      var image = canvas.item(0);
      var backend = fabric.filterBackend;
      if (backend && backend.evictCachesForKey) {
        backend.evictCachesForKey(image.cacheKey);
        backend.evictCachesForKey(image.cacheKey + '_filtered');
      }
      canvas.item(0).applyFilters();
      canvas.renderAll();
      fabric.util.requestAnimFrame(render);
    });

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fabric.js/2.2.3/fabric.min.js"></script>
<button id="play">play</button>
<canvas id="c" width="300" height="300"></canvas>
<video crossorigin="anonymous" id="video1" style="display: none" class="canvas-img" width="480" height="360">
  <source id="video_src1" src="http://commondatastorage.googleapis.com/gtv-videos-bucket/sample/BigBuckBunny.mp4" type="video/mp4">
</video>
```

Comment: is it possible to download/export that video with applied effects? If yes, then how can I download/Export it?

Comment: there is an api in the browsers that let you create a video from a canvas.

Comment: @AndreaBogazzi What kind of API? Can you please suggest?

Comment: What are you asking for? i do not understand.

Comment: @AndreaBogazzi Please check this question I have added, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54266023/how-to-export-fabricjs-canvas-in-video-format-like-mp4-with-sound

Comment: @AndreaBogazzi is it possible to add video as canvas background?

Comment: Yes. that would be canvas.backgroundImage = videoObject. Still you have to render continuosly.

Comment: @UmeshPatadiya checkout https://github.com/ffmpegwasm/ffmpeg.wasm/ for canvas recording